# javascript toFixed(2) not working

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code:

```
var desconto = document.getElementById('desconto').value;
var portes = document.getElementById('portes').value;
var pr_equipamentos = document.getElementById('pr_total_equipamentos_escondido').value;
var pr_total;

pr_total = (pr_equipamentos * ((100-desconto)/100)) + portes;
pr_total = pr_total.toFixed(2);
alert(pr_total);

document.getElementById('pr_total_proposta').innerHTML = pr_total + " €";
```

The ID's `desconto`, `portes` and `pr_total_equipamentos_escondido` are input type in a form.

In this case I'm not able to use the `toFixed(2)`. The first formula of **pr_total** gives me the number: `1324.7865372846` and the next step is not working `(pr_total = pr_total.toFixed(2))`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please describe the "not working" part. What happens, and what was supposed to happen.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or some other executable version of the problem?

Comment: In this case, the "alert(pr_total)" doesn´t give me the message. If I delete the line "pr_total = pr_total.toFixed(2)" the alert is working, so I suppose the line "pr_total = pr_total.toFixed(2)" has some error. My intention is to have the following alert message: "1324.78".

Comment: If you've bothered to take a look at the console, you would have seen an error message: `TypeError: pr_total.toFixed is not a function.` This happens since values of `input`s are strings. Convert them to numbers before maths...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define a var, in JavaScript it is a string, so you need to parse.

try:

```
pr_total = parseFloat(pr_total).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Most likely - this conversion to number should be one line above.

Answer (score -2):

```
_txt3.value = (parseFloat(t1) - parseFloat(t2));


_txt3.value = parseFloat(_txt3.value).toFixed(2);
```